# Flash doesn't load in Chrome browser. Says "Couldn't load plugin."

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, flash

I noticed that while HTML5 videos work fine, flash videos do not load. I have researched this and have tried numerous things to no avail.

1) I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling Chrome (deleting everything, even the Google folder in localappdata).

2) I've tried disabling/enabling Adobe Flash Player from chrome://plugins/

3) I've tried resetting all settings from chrome://settings/

4) I've tried disabling all extensions.

When I uninstall and then reinstall Chrome, however, the problem goes away. I am able to view flash videos. But when I sign into Chrome and have all of my bookmarks, settings, and extensions synced automatically, the problem comes back.

Below is the list of extensions I use:

Empty New Tab Page

Google Docs Offline

History Eraser App

Mailto: for Gmail™

Reddit Enhancement Suite

uBlock Origin

What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you try uninstalling all your extensions? That is the only part of chrome that is synced and cancreate an issue like this.

Comment: @Private I uninstalled all extensions, but nothing changed. So with all the extensions uninstalled, I went ahead and uninstalled/reinstalled Chrome. The flash videos played fine now. So I tried installing an extension one by one starting with uBlock Origin. Immediately, the flash videos stopped working. Uninstalling that extension at that point did nothing as well.

Comment: Good job, you got the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a whole lotta digging, I found the answer here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?#!topic/chrome/mxwrMGVA6FQ

> When the flash player stops loading from one day to the next, it's
>   possible that a recent DLL update to
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\PepperFlash\20.0.0.xxx\pepflashplayer.dll is the cause. The xxx
>   can vary over time: 267, 286..
>
> To test the DLL, hide/rename it as pepflashplayerHide.dll. Close/open
>   Chrome, which will now use it's builtin DLL. If the player works,
>   you've found the culprit. You can stop with the Hide workaround or try
>   to fix the problem.
>
> To correct the problem, delete the PepperFlash folder. Close, open
>   Chrome: the flash player should load. If the problem reappears (after
>   the folder auto updates), there may be permissions problem (see
>   below).
>
> --Details-- The DLL won't load if it's 32/64 bit-type doesn't match the bit-type of Chrome. A mismatch can occur when you switch 32/64-bit
>   Chrome versions and there was a flash player security update lately
>   (here 12/24/15).
>
> Type about:version in the address box to see the Chrome bit-type.
>
> To check the type of the DLL update, look at it's size. (See the
>   PepperFlash path above) Sizes under 17000KB are 32-bit, over 28000KB
>   are 64-bit.
>
> If the bit-types don't match, delete the 20.0.0.xxx folder. If the
>   bit-types match, there can still be a permissions problem - delete the
>   PepperFlash folder.
>
> When you hide the DLL or delete the folder, Chrome will fall back to
>   it's builtin version and flash should work.
>
> After deleting the folder, you'll get an auto-update soon (usually <30
>   min). Or you can update it immediately from about:components.
>
> If the problem returns with the update (watch the PepperFlash folder),
>   try running Chrome as Administrator. If this lets the plugin load,
>   there may be permission problems.
>
> You can circumvent the permissions failure by hiding the DLL again,
>   see above. This will block additional updates (to this 20.0.0.xxx) and
>   use the less secure builtin DLL. Quick, but not optimal.
>
> The better approach is to fix the folder permissions.. You only need
>   to fix the 20.0.0.xxx folder, the critical permission is 'Read and
>   Execute'. Try this succinct [Best Answer](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/_AUhHQ-t-fE) (old but good) or see
>   this [recent longer one](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/kU5XoT53ZTI).
>
> The 32/64-bit conflict is being worked as [bug 546017](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=546017).
>   Institutional users may see the same "Couldn't load plugin" failure,
>   but this is related to network share permissions. See [bug 572131](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=572131)
>   for details.

Comment: I know it's not the done thing here, but I wanted to say thanks anyway. In my case, the DLL simply disappeared (perhaps due to a system restore, but it was only back a few hours so this shouldn't have even happened). Either way, reinstalling had no effect but deleting the PepperFlash folder worked in seconds! Saved me hours of wasted time.